# DotNetNuke Template with child tabs

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, dotnetnuke

I'm wanting to create a template in DotNetNuke which can be restored to a different portal. I did this successfully but it only took the page and it's content. What I was actually wanting was for it to restore the child pages of the page templated as well.

Can someone please tell me if this is even possible and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you created a page template.  What you are after is a portal template.  You can create one by navigating to Host | Portals and clicking Export Portal Template.

Comment: I don't want to export the whole portal just pages with sub pages.

Comment: I think those are your only two options: page template or portal template.  You could manually remove everything else from your portal template, then apply it to the current site via the Site Wizard page (under Admin), which would probably get you most of the way there...

Comment: @bdukes - Thanks! Site Wizard was the answer.